# docker rocker/shiny running, but in the browser, it shows directory

Tags: r, docker, shiny

I have a question regarding the docker rocker/shiny

The docker is running by executing the following:

```
docker run -d -p 80:3838 \
    -v /mylocaldirectory/:/srv/shiny-server/ \
        rocker/shiny
```

however, when i put : http://localhost:80
it shows the webpage with
Index of
rather than the dashboard.

I would like to know what can be the possible reason?
my thought was maybe the format of the r file? I have tried as app.R or app.r
but it shows the same thing on the brower.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The [usage guide](https://github.com/rocker-org/shiny#usage) does mention:

https://github.com/rocker-org/shiny

> If you have an app in `/srv/shinyapps/appdir`, you can run the app by visiting http://localhost/appdir/

So make sure to go to the right subfolder, with [RMarkdown documents](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/rmarkdown.html) (`*.Rmd`)